# How to have cmake chache file not in c++ source directory

Tags: linux, cmake

Maybe stupid question, but how do I change directory where cmake files gonna be created, so I can keep my project kinda cleaner.
For example when I run `cmake -S. -B./src` it is not gonna create files and directories like cmakeChache, cmakefiles and other in my source directory.
Btw I running linux.

Comment: If there are no weird design choices in your cmake project, you should be  able to specify arbitrary directories as build directory. `cmake -S . -B /some/random/path` Both `-S` and `-B` options can be used to specify any absolute or relative path and the build directory doesn't even need to exist at the time of calling `cmake`. There are of course issues possible issues, if you're lacking permissions to access the files/create the directories necessary, but other than that the choice is yours...

Comment: Btw: usually I use a directory like `build64`, `build_debug` or similar either located in the same dir as the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` or in the parent dir. Of course this assumes this directory is not used for anything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood how to do it. I just had `CMakeLists.txt` file and my source c++ code in another directories and I don't know how to set source path to `CMakeLists.txt` file and c++ source in the same time so I just moved `CMakeLists.txt` file to source directory and now I don't have to set build path to path of my source code.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is:

```
cmake -S <PATH/TO/SOURCE_FILES> -B <PATH/TO/BUILD_OUTPUT>
cmake --build <PATH/TO/BUILD_OUTPUT> --target all
```

It is recommended that `<PATH/TO/BUILD_OUTPUT>` is not a sub directory of `<PATH/TO/SOURCE_FILES>`.

It should be parallel to the sources:

```
+-PATH
  +-TO
    +-BUILD_OUTPUT
    +-otherstuff
    +-SOURCE_FILES
```

Note: Most CMS(e.g. git) can be configured to not consider generated files.